# Wix 3.6 Burn: unmanaged custom UI

Tags: wix, windows-installer, burn

I want to package multiple MSIs into a single install package, hence I am using Burn from Wix3.6.

I want to have a simple user interface allowing to select which package(s) should be installed.

I understand the standard BA (wixstdba.dll) does not provide this functionnality and that I need to write my own BA.

I have been looking at project 'wixstdba' from the 'wix36-sources' package as an example of a C++ BA. To get started I have tried simply rebuilding the project and adding the resulting DLL to my Bundle as follows:

```
<Bundle 
    Name="$(var.ProductName)"
     Version="$(var.ProductVersion)"
    Manufacturer="$(var.VendorName)"
    UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)" >
    <BootstrapperApplication SourceFile="wixstdba.dll" />
    <Chain>
    ...
```

I succesfully built the Bundle:

```
light -ext WixBalExtension.dll -ext WixUIExtension -ext WixUtilExtension installer-v$(VERSION).wixobj -o installer-v$(VERSION).exe

candle -o installer-v$(VERSION).wixobj bundle.wxs -d"Platform=x64"
```

However, when I run the resulting .exe, nothing happens. No UI appears, no software is installed and no error message.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

When you run the .exe, it should create a log file in your system's %TEMP% folder.  This should tell you if any errors are being encountered.  The file name will be the product name (with spaces replaced with underscores).  The easiest way to find it is to open a Windows Explorer window, type "%TEMP%" for the folder name, and sort by Date Modified desc.  The top file is likely the right one.

It is likely that the bootstrapper is running, but when it attempts to load your code it is unable to load some dependency, or otherwise has some error. Hopefully, the log will provide enough hints for you to find the issue.

If you end up needing to add additional libraries/files to be used by your BA, add them to the bundle payload files, like this:

```
  <BootstrapperApplicationRef SourceFile="wixstdba.dll" >
    <Payload SourceFile="$(var.ReferencedProject.TargetDir)\file.needed.at.runtime" />
  </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
```

This will place the file in the same folder as your unpacked BA at runtime.